# linker error, wont compile on Windows but compiles on Mac, Qt but all the libraries are already linked and fine

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile my program, and it already worked on another machine(Mac), I just copied it to a new machine(Windows), because the client wants it for Windows 10, and now it simply won't recognize all of my qtwidgets, it doesn't matters if it find the correct library.

I already check for libraries (qtCore, QtSql, etc) and they are fine and linked, and still get warnings **"undefined reference to object"**, I'll paste what I get from the output window.

I'm using netbeans Qt 5.12.8 on Windows, the program was made on mac Qt 5.11.3

I installed MinGW g++ using the Mkspace win32-g++, its the only mk space that seems to work, but cant go further, I already tried different Qmakes and mkspaces, but it only gets worse.

Program

```
pantalla_principal.cpp --> https://pastebin.com/jSzwT42s
pantalla_principal.h ---> https://pastebin.com/qH2F4XaG
Login.cpp --->  https://pastebin.com/JDXcrYYe
Login.h --->  https://pastebin.com/e5PsDM5g
ui_Login.h --> https://pastebin.com/7SqX62Pt 
ui_Pantalla_Principal.h --> https://pastebin.com/vNByjKgG
```

**output window**

```
 cd 'C:\Users\Patron\Desktop\Code Projects\Sistema_Silo'
 C:\make-3.81-bin\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug QMAKE=/C/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/bin/qmake.exe
 "/C/make-3.81-bin/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=/C/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/bin/qmake.exe SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
 make[1]: se ingresa al directorio `C:/Users/Patron/Desktop/Code Projects/Sistema_Silo'
 c:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/bin/qmake.exe VPATH=. -spec win32-g++ -o qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.pro
 mv -f qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.mk
 "c:/make-3.81-bin/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/qt-Debug.mk dist/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/Sistema_Silo.exe
 make[2]: se ingresa al directorio `C:/Users/Patron/Desktop/Code Projects/Sistema_Silo'
 g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -Wall -W -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -Inbproject -I. -IC:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtSql -IC:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtCore -I. -I. -I/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o build/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/Login.o Login.cpp

In file included from C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtCore/QVariant:1,
             from ui_Login.h:12,
             from Login.h:17,
             from Login.cpp:14:
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtCore/qvariant.h: In constructor 'QVariant::QVariant(QVariant&&)':
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtCore/qvariant.h:273:25: warning: implicitly-declared 'constexpr QVariant::Private& QVariant::Private::operator=(const QVariant::Private&)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-copy]
  273 |     { other.d = Private(); }
      |                         ^
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtCore/qvariant.h:399:16: note: because 'QVariant::Private' has user-provided 'QVariant::Private::Private(const QVariant::Private&)'
  399 |         inline Private(const Private &other) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
      |                ^~~~~~~

 windres -i Sistema_Silo_resource.rc -o build/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/Sistema_Silo_resource_res.o --include-dir=. -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN
  g++ -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o dist/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/Sistema_Silo.exe build/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/Login.o build/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/Pantalla_Principal.o build/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/main_Pantalla_Principal.o build/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/moc_Login.o build/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/moc_Pantalla_Principal.o  C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/lib/libQt5Widgetsd.a 
 C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/lib/libQt5Guid.a C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/lib/libQt5Sqld.a C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/lib/libQt5Cored.a build/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/Sistema_Silo_resource_res.o  -lmingw32 C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/lib/libqtmaind.a 

 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/Login.o: in function `ZN9EmbarquesC2Ev':
 C:\Users\Patron\Desktop\Code Projects\Sistema_Silo/Login.cpp:20: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7QWidgetC2EPS_6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Patron\Desktop\Code Projects\Sistema_Silo/Login.cpp:22: undefined reference to `_imp___Z13qFlagLocationPKc'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Patron\Desktop\Code Projects\Sistema_Silo/Login.cpp:22: undefined reference to `_imp___Z13qFlagLocationPKc'
...
```

this keeps going for all my qtwidgets so I had to trim it, but it's basically the same warning

```
...
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/Login.o: in function `ZN9Embarques8AprovadoEv':
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/msvc2015_64/include/QtCore/qarraydata.h:239: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_jj'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/Pantalla_Principal.o: in function `ZN18Pantalla_PrincipalC2Ev':
C:\Users\Patron\Desktop\Code Projects\Sistema_Silo/Pantalla_Principal.cpp:31: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11QMainWindowC2EP7QWidget6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Patron\Desktop\Code Projects\Sistema_Silo/ui_Pantalla_Principal.h:353: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8QPalette8setBrushENS_10ColorGroupENS_9ColorRoleERK6QBrush'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/moc_Login.o:moc_Login.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV9Embarques[__ZTV9Embarques]+0x70): undefined reference to `QWidget::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent*)'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/msvc_2015_64_qt_5.12.8_win32-g++-Windows/Sistema_Silo.exe] Error 1
make[2]: se sale del directorio `C:/Users/Patron/Desktop/Code Projects/Sistema_Silo'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio `C:/Users/Patron/Desktop/Code Projects/Sistema_Silo'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 26s)
```

Here is the makefile for this program, its kind of big so I used paste bin, hope it works: https://pastebin.com/Jg9Jz69h

Edit 1: I made my own custom Mkfile in order to point exactly to mingw32-g++ compiler, I set it as a mkspace and I still got the same warnings.

Here is my Output, I had to trim it but its all the same:

```
cd 'C:\Users\Patron\Desktop\Code Projects\Sistema_Silo'
C:\make-3.81-bin\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug QMAKE=/C/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/mingw73_64/bin/qmake.exe
"/C/make-3.81-bin/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=/C/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/mingw73_64/bin/qmake.exe SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: se ingresa al directorio `C:/Users/Patron/Desktop/Code Projects/Sistema_Silo'
c:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/mingw73_64/bin/qmake.exe VPATH=. -spec win32-g++-mingw32 -o qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.pro
mv -f qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.mk
"c:/make-3.81-bin/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/qt-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Sistema_Silo.exe
make[2]: se ingresa al directorio `C:/Users/Patron/Desktop/Code Projects/Sistema_Silo'
mingw32-g++ -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Sistema_Silo.exe build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Login.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Pantalla_Principal.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main_Pantalla_Principal.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/moc_Login.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/moc_Pantalla_Principal.o  C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/mingw73_64/lib/libQt5Widgetsd.a C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/mingw73_64/lib/libQt5Guid.a C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/mingw73_64/lib/libQt5Sqld.a C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/mingw73_64/lib/libQt5Cored.a build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Sistema_Silo_resource_res.o  -lmingw32 C:/Qt/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/mingw73_64/lib/libqtmaind.a -LC:/openssl/lib -LC:/Utils/my_sql/mysql-5.6.11-winx64/lib -LC:/Utils/postgresql/pgsql/lib -lshell32 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Login.o: in function `ZN9EmbarquesC2Ev':
C:\Users\Patron\Desktop\Code Projects\Sistema_Silo/Login.cpp:20: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7QWidgetC2EPS_6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Patron\Desktop\Code Projects\Sistema_Silo/Login.cpp:22: undefined reference to `_imp___Z13qFlagLocationPKc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Patron\Desktop\Code Projects\Sistema_Silo/Login.cpp:22: undefined reference to `_imp___Z13qFlagLocationPKc'
....
....
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/moc_Pantalla_Principal.o:moc_Pantalla_Principal.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV18Pantalla_Principal[__ZTV18Pantalla_Principal]+0xf4): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QWidget::metric(QPaintDevice::PaintDeviceMetric) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/moc_Pantalla_Principal.o:moc_Pantalla_Principal.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV18Pantalla_Principal[__ZTV18Pantalla_Principal]+0xf8): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QWidget::initPainter(QPainter*) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/moc_Pantalla_Principal.o:moc_Pantalla_Principal.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV18Pantalla_Principal[__ZTV18Pantalla_Principal]+0xfc): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QWidget::redirected(QPoint*) const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/moc_Pantalla_Principal.o:moc_Pantalla_Principal.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV18Pantalla_Principal[__ZTV18Pantalla_Principal]+0x100): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QWidget::sharedPainter() const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Sistema_Silo.exe] Error 1
make[2]: se sale del directorio `C:/Users/Patron/Desktop/Code Projects/Sistema_Silo'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio `C:/Users/Patron/Desktop/Code Projects/Sistema_Silo'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 6s)
```

Edit 2:
I'm using the make command from Msys seems to work a little better, I still got the undefined reference error but at least doesn't point to errors in the qt files, which it is a linker error anyway.

https://pastebin.com/ZDnCF8zn  mkfile

https://pastebin.com/WA34zcrT  new makefile for mingw32-g++

Edit 3:
I literally used every compiler installed in my computer, from g++ to mingw g++ and qt g++, also used the makes that comes with qt, got nothing. also installed qt 5.8 just in case an old version can do the trick, nothing.

I need options, I literally ran out of ideas, I even created a brand new project just in case, didn't work.

---

Edit 4:
I installed QT 5.11.3, and used the Mingw 5.3 32 bits build and it somehow manage to compile partially, let me explain, my issue was it wasn't compiling nor creating no .exe file at all, by using the Qmake qt 5.11.3 it manage to compile but it had several errors

1. there are missing .dll files, that i had to copy manually (QT5Guid.dll, QT5Core.dll, etc) to the build folder, not big deal
2. when compiling i get errors from the file qstyleoption.h for basically every single function, just like this

Paste bin -->  https://pastebin.com/9rzXR69i

I do get an .exe file but every time I try to run it, I got the warning **the application could not be started correctly 0xc00007b, press ok to continue**
according to Google that is a problem from Microsoft redistributable c++ (I reinstalled and got the 2015-2019 x64 and x86 versions)

so it was basically a partial win

Comment: When using MinGW, all libraries must be built with minGW (you can't mix the two compilers for C++), but the Qt you are using is built with MSVC 2015. Use the minGW build.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld , plz check edit 1, already used the MinGW 7.3 32 bits build and mingw32-g+ compiler like you sugest, still nothing.

Comment: I don’t know what the issue is then, assuming that there was no ABI change or similar between minGW 9.x and 7.x, I don’t see why this shouldn’t work… maybe include the actual compilation (not just linking) in the log. (is there a switch for 32 bit vs. 64 bit build? I don’t see anything explicit)

Comment: sorry i dont follow, you mean the makefile? and I already check the version of the compilers, they are all v9.2.0 ( g++,ming32-g++, c++), but the instalation folder was mingw73_64, that was my mistake, anyway i have been using the compilers from that place and also installed Qt 5.8 just in case, im starting to believe theres an inside bug regarding to use diferent version, if i cant find a solution im gona start the program all over again from scrath, thats 2 monts down to the bin if that happend.